# How do I convert a Vec <&str> to Vec <String>?

Tags: rust, data-science, arff

```
let parts: Vec<String> = line.split_whitespace().collect();
let parts: Vec<String> = map(AsRef::as_ref).line.split_whitespace().collect();
if parts.len() >= 3 {
    let attribute_name = parts[1].to_string();
    let attribute_type = parts[2].to_lowercase();
    let attribute = match attribute_type.as_str() {
        "numeric" => Attribute::Numeric,
        "date" => Attribute::Date(parts.get(3).cloned()),
        "string" => Attribute::String,
        "nominal" => {
            let nominal_values: Vec<String> = parts[3..]
                .iter()
                .map(|s| s.trim_matches(|c| c == '{' || c == '}' || c == ',').to_string())
                .collect();
            Attribute::Nominal(nominal_values)
        }
```

[image]

My goal is to implement an algorithm in Rust for loading and reading .arff files. It reads an .arff file, extract information from header, attributes and instances, then prints it on the output. Each attribute is represented as a pair (name, type) in array attributes, and instances are stored as arrays of attribute values ​​in array instances.

Comment: I do not understand the line `let parts: Vec<String> = map(AsRef::as_ref).line.split_whitespace().collect();`. But based on the error in the image you're sharing, you can use `map` to parse from `&str` to `String`  [see the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=81813e897d8cda555bf4998757e9911f)

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much, but there's still an error. It says cannot find function 'map' in this scope.

Comment: can you share the error?

Comment: let parts: Vec<String> = map(AsRef::as_ref).line.split_whitespace().collect();

"expected function, found crate 'map'... not a function"

Comment: Please don't post images of error messages or code, but post the actual text instead so stackoverflow remains accessible and searchable. (Also, the text output you get from `cargo check` is sometimes easier to understand than the IDE error output.)

Comment: @Madhouse1999 what this line does exactly? What is the reason for the existence of this line? Have you defined the `map` function or what `map` function are you trying call?

Comment: @Madhouse1999 Please could you share a little more context on this? Because as I see your code that line is too much.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to map the values of the vector. Something like this:

```
let parts: Vec<String> = line.split_whitespace().map(|v| v.to_string()).collect();
```