How to convert polars Series of strings to Vec<String>?
I am using Rust with cargo 1.80.1 and polars = "0.42.0", and I want to convert a polars Series of Strings to Vec<String> as more common type, which is to be used by my other functions without polars. For additional information, in Python pandas.Series, it is like this: ds.to_list().
I am a beginner to Rust and I could not find a solution. Here are similar posts but not help with my case.

How to convert a Series of Strings into an Array or Vec of Strings. It involves something about .lit() and the comments suggest group_by(). Irrelevant to my question.
How to get a Vec from polars Series or ChunkedArray?. It is about a Series of numbers, not of strings. One of their command suggests .utf8(), but I tried, this method is not available (anymore). And I cannot find anything about utf8() on https://docs.pola.rs, for the current version.

use polars::prelude::*;

fn my_func() -> Vec<String> {
    let ds: Series = Series::new("name", &vec!["apple", "orange", "banana"]);
    // Convert s to Vec<String>
    let result: Vec<String> = ds.str().unwrap(); // Not working, res type is &ChunkedArray<StringType>
    result  // It should be a vector of ["apple", "orange", "banana"].
}

Can anyone please help me? Thanks!

Looks like you've omitted the .to_vec*() or .into_iter*()+.collect() calls shown in the answers to your second linked Q&A.

to_vec*() requires T: PolarsNumericType which str doesn't fulfill for obvious reasons, but .into_no_null_iter().collect() does work to collect a Vec<&str>.

Call to reopen. This question is different from the suggested question (How to get a Vec from polars Series or ChunkedArray?) in the reason for closing. As I already mentioned in my question, that post only addressed numbers, but my question is about string. The solution there cannot be applied to here. And my question is more specific about strings.

@aura the solution there works by simply switching the data type. No other change needed.

@cafce25, no the solution there does not work here. The solution there is s.i32()?.into_no_null_iter().collect();. If you simply adapt it here let result: Vec<&str> = ds.str()?.into_no_null_iter().collect(); you'll get an error in the question mark: the ? operator can only be used in a function that returns Result or Option (or another type that implements FromResidual)
the trait FromResidual<Result<Infallible, PolarsError>> is not implemented for Vec<std::string::String>.

Yes, you'll have to adapt it slightly. That's not a new question. That's the same fundamental problem with slightly different cirumstances.

@cafce25, continue with my comments above. Even if you use this code to get a Vec<&str>, as let result: Vec<&str> = ds.str().unwrap().into_no_null_iter().collect();, the result cannot be returned, since the error msg:
cannot return value referencing local variable ds
returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
So the actual solution is let result: Vec<String> = ds         .str()         .unwrap()         .into_no_null_iter()         .map(|x| x.to_string())         .collect();

That's part of a different also arleady asked question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76461002/how-do-i-convert-a-vec-str-to-vec-string

@cafce25, the reason I created this question is that the other post has no clear answer/solution to the case with a vector of strings. And their comments gave wrong suggestion about utf8(). You added a comment about str() there, and that is later than my question. But still not a full/working answer.
